# How to get pacmd to connect to the PulseAudio daemon on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio

I was trying to set up pulse audio on Fedora 38 to have a virtual audio cable out from OBS into my web browser. However, when running any pacmd command, I get the error, "No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon." However, I can open graphical pulse audio volume control, and it works fine.

Attempting to change the pulse runtime path has not fixed the problem, and my system does not have a pulse user group.